# Best method for implementing tile map. Python-kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am using kivy and python to make a demo of a game. I intend to make the game run on Android. One of the problems I faced is how to render the tile map such that I can move it around.

I have tried the following methods and faced the following issues:
1) use individual image widgets to load each tile to be displayed. Issue: Moving around makes the game lag since I have to reload all the image widgets.
2) merge the individual tiles into a huge PNG image and then load parts of the image to fit the screen. Issue: impractical for large maps and also unable to load only a part of the image.

What is the best way to do this? Btw, I intend to use large tilemaps.

Comment: why dont u try using kivent?

Comment: Good idea, but I would love to create the code for rendering the map myself after getting a basic idea of how actual games render tile maps